# How to seperate two statements (or the semicolon's equivalent)

Tags: haskell

```
oddSquareSum :: Integer
oddSquareSum =
    let oddSquares = filter odd $ map (^2) [1..]
        belowLimit = takeWhile (<10000) oddSquares
    in  sum belowLimit
    --extra code to print the list of integers
    show belowLimit
```

This is the code to print the sum of squares of odd numbers. The list of squared odd numbers is in the list, `belowLimit` and how can i print it?

Adding it as an extra line at the end, gives compilation errors as the `show` function call is treated as `sum` function's argument.

Comment: So what output do you want ? An `Integer` or a `String` ?

Comment: On one hand, you need to read up on how Haskell chooses to represent IO effects in its static type system. On the other hand, you are probably looking for [Debug.Trace.trace](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:trace)

Comment: @sibi, to print the temporary list - `belowLimit` value like [1 9 25....] etc

Comment: Note that `show` does not print the result. Instead it converts it to a `String` (in such a way that it can be evaluated again back to the original value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for completeness, if you just want to put in some temporary code for debugging and neither want to change the signature nor split up the function, you also have the option to use `traceShow` from `Debug.Trace`:

```
import Debug.Trace (traceShow)

oddSquareSum :: Integer
oddSquareSum =
    let oddSquares = filter odd $ map (^2) [1..]
        belowLimit = takeWhile (<10000) oddSquares
    in  traceShow belowLimit $ sum belowLimit
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't, not with the type you currently have.  I wouldn't recommend changing the type in this case either.  Haskell makes a type-level distinction between code that only computes values and code that has side effects, such as printing to the screen.  It's a weird concept at first, but it becomes very helpful for reasoning about your code, even in languages that don't enforce it (I use this strategy a lot in Python).  Instead, write another function that will print the value, such as

```
printAnswer :: IO ()        -- The IO means that this can have side effects
printAnswer = print oddSquareSum

oddSquareSum :: Integer
oddSquareSum =
    let oddSquares = filter odd $ map (^2) [1..]
        belowLimit = takeWhile (<10000) oddSquares
    in sum belowLimit
```

Then you can run `printAnswer` from GHCi after loading your source file, or you can have `main` call `printAnswer`, then compile your file into an executable.  If you're going to use GHCi, you can skip writing this wrapper altogether and just type `oddSquareSum` directly into the console to see its value.

Comment: thanks bheklilr... i am trying to print a debug statement to see the values of the list, `belowLimit`. i am okay to change the type of `oddSquareSum` as `IO()`.

Comment: @MadhavanKumar why not break it out into a separate function then? I find that if you want to know intermediate values then it's complex enough to pull out as a standalone computation. Write a function that computes belowLimit and print the result of that instead. Yes, it means that you will have a lot of small bits of code in your file, but haskell is usually quite simple to refactor, and keeping it broken up keeps it more reusable, too.